# Computing Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors using Numpy from File

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compute the Eigenvector and Eigenvalue of data that is inside a file. The file itself has a list of numbers.

How would you compute both of them based on the information in the file itself?

```
import numpy as np
f = open("cloud.data",'r')
file_object = f.read()
new_file_object = file_object.center(5)
print (new_file_object)

m = np.matrix(file_object)
eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(m)
eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(m)
print (eigenvalues)
print (eigenvectors)
```

Comment: you can just do ````eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(m)````

Comment: Which problem are you currently having?

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (that's the error)